# unable to get both latitude and longitude from address, I get one of them either latitude or longitude

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I am working on an app which  works with  latitude and and longitude after a user input an address. I'm utilizing  Geocoder  to get the latitude and longitude from the Input address. But the issue is both are  returned with associated address from the Geocoder  but I'm only able to read one of them. following is the code I'm using:

```
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> addresses;
    double[] cordinates = new double[2];
    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locName, 1);
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            cordinates[0] = addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
            cordinates[1] = addresses.get(0).getLongitude();//unable to get this one 


            return cordinates;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return null;
}
```

in the above cases I'm able to get latitude but unable to get the longitude. I known this after debugging. Now when I swap them like

```
                 cordinates[1] = addresses.get(0).getLongitude();                
                 cordinates[0] = addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
```

Now I  get Longitude but not the latitude.
what is the problem here?

Comment: Include exception stack trace in your question

Comment: @MaxZavernutiy the code jump to the last of the method and return null when it read the second cordinate.there is no exception stack produceed

Comment: Try assigning the `Address` to a local variable `Address address = addresses.get(0)` and then use the local variable instead. Looks like the `List` is consuming the `Address` when you call `get`. Not sure why this happens (if it happens).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working fine. Since you are debugging your code with breakpoints when it encounters the
`return cordinates;` it goes to 
`return null;`
 It only happens while debugging. It always returns the correct value. You can check returned values by inserting a log statement.

```
 {
     .....
     double[] coordinates = getLongLat("Your address");
     Log.wtf(TAG,"Lat:"+coordinates[0]+" Long:"+coordinates[1]);// This will log the correct values
     .....
 }


 public double[]  getLongLat(String address){
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> addresses;
    double[] cordinates = new double[2];

   try {
       addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, 1);
       if (addresses.size() > 0) {
          Address address1 = addresses.get(0);
          cordinates[0] = address1.getLatitude();
          cordinates[1]  = address1.getLongitude();
          return cordinates;
    }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
       return null;
}
```

Comment: Yes it is working fine, thanks for the information. but I still don't know why the  debug statement skip the first return statement and return null?

Comment: @SayyedErfanian It does not skip the first return statement. When it encounters the return statement it goes to the end of the block of code. And also you accepted the wrong answer. Can you please correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this working code :

```
AutoCompleteTextView acGooglePlaces = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.ac_edit_my_event_places);

    acGooglePlaces.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(GooglePlaces.this, R.layout.auto_complete_text_layout));
    acGooglePlaces.requestFocus();

    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                List<Address> returnedaddresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(acGooglePlaces.getText().toString(),1);

                if(!returnedaddresses.isEmpty()){

                    String latForVol = String.valueOf(returnedaddresses.get(0).getLatitude());
                    String longForVol = String.valueOf(returnedaddresses.get(0).getLongitude());

                    Log.e("Lat", latForVol);
                    Log.e("Long", longForVol);
                    Log.e("Location", acGooglePlaces.getText().toString());

                }else {
                    Log.e("Check", "Please give the correct address");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: @SayyedErfanian you got latitude or longitude? or else you get into else loop?

Comment: it is resolved.....the error was the return statement in the if is skipped and the return null at end is executed instead. the last return statement was placed at wrong place. I forgot to place it within the else statement. yee working on empty stomach for long time trolled me. thank you for answer .

Answer (score 0):

```
public static LatLng reverseGeocoding(Context context, String locationName){
    if(!Geocoder.isPresent()){
        Log.w("zebia", "Geocoder implementation not present !");
    }
    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());

    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(locationName, 1);



    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(Geocoding.class.getName(), "not possible finding LatLng for Address : " + locationName);
    }

    if(addresses.size() > 0){
            Log.d("zebia", "reverse Geocoding : locationName " + locationName + "Latitude " + addresses.get(0).getLatitude() );
            return new LatLng(addresses.get(0).getLatitude(), addresses.get(0).getLongitude());
    }else{
            //use http api
    }
    return null;
}
```